# Problems with Coldfusion Form Submissions

Tags: forms, coldfusion, dreamweaver

I'm having a bit of trouble with my form submission, and I'm afraid I need some advice.

I have a form where I want a user to submit some text, and when they press submit it will take them to an action page where the input will be processed.  I wrote some code, only to figure out when I test it in Dreamweaver the submit button isn't working correctly.

Code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<cfinclude template="head.cfm">

<cfform name="select_action" action="testaction.cfm" method="post">
    Enter some text here 
    <input type="text" size="50" value="Enter some text here" maxlength="150"  name="someText"><br>

    <INPUT TYPE="RESET" NAME="reset" VALUE="Reset Form">
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 

    <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="submit" VALUE="Submit Form">
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
</cfform>

<cfinclude template="foot.cfm">
```

I have Dreamweaver correctly configured for testing, because I can reset the form and it shows up properly etc.  Just the submit button doesn't take me to anywhere.

I feel that there's something extremely obvious I'm missing, any advice?

Thanks for your time,

Jordan

Comment: What's the code in `testaction.cfm`? And what do you mean the submit button `isnt working`?

Comment: need to explain what you mean by "not working". Also, you are using "cfform" but not using any "cfinput" or "cfselect" etc. I would scrap cfform and simply use <form> and make sure and use an "enctype" attribute.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the replies.  What I mean by "not working" is that it's not submitting anything or taking me to the other page, for whatever reason.  All the testaction.cfm is supposed to do is just sit there, it was purely for testing purposes just to see if I could get the form to work.  Now, this could be a misunderstanding of how these things are supposed to work.  I figured it would redirect me to the cfm, even if I didn't do anything with the data.  I'll take your suggestions in mind and get rid of the cfform and try the other methods you mention.

Comment: Jordan, I actually copied your form (without the footer/header includes) to a test CFM page and ran it. It submits for me. Either something is fooling with the action param of your form OR you are being "fooled" by a redirect on the testaction.cfm page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While testing in Dreamweaver may seem like a good idea, I haven't found it helpful at all.  You should have your page open in several browsers at once, such as Firefox and Chrome.  Test the behavior of your pages in real browsers, not Dreamweaver.

Also, I would use CFFORM only if you need CFFORM. From the looks of your elements, you don't need it.

Comment: I am so glad I could help you out!

Comment: @jorblume: While you have accepted this answer, I don't see a solution here. What was the problem?

Comment: Hi Al, the problem was that Dreamweaver was being difficult.  After testing my code using browsers it did work fine.  Thanks!